# Trying to copy data from vertica table into csv using vsql

Tags: unix, psql, vsql

Was trying to export data from vertica table to CSV file, but some data contain comma "," in values which pushed to other column.

```
 vsql -h server_address -p 5433 -U username -w password -F $',' -A -o sadumpfile_3.csv -c 
 "select full_name from company_name;" -P footer=off
```

Vertica table data and expected csv:

```
   full_name
   ----------
   Samsun pvt, ltd
   Apple inc
   abc, pvt ltd
```

Ouput sadumpfile_3.csv

```
   full_name
   -------------        ---------
   Samsunpvt              ltd
   Apple inc
   abc                    pvt ltd
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Default behaviour (I have the four environment variables `VSQL_USER`, `VSQL_PASSWORD`, `VSQL_HOST` and `VSQL_DATABASE` set):

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -c "select full_name from company_name"
    full_name    
-----------------
 Apple inc
 Samsun pvt, ltd
 abc, pvt ltd
(3 rows)
```

The simplest way to achieve what you were trying:

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -F ',' -A -c "select full_name from company_name;" -Pfooter
full_name
Apple inc
Samsun pvt, ltd
abc, pvt ltd
```

Note that the only commas are the ones already existing in the strings. If you only export one column, there's no field delimiter in the output.

I can only suppose that you want to have the output so that you can, for example, import it into Excel as CSV. If the field delimiter exists in a string, you would need to enclose the string with (usually double) quotes.

Vertica has a function that encloses a string with double quotes: `QUOTE_IDENT()`:

```
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ vsql -F ',' -A \
 -c "select QUOTE_IDENT(full_name) AS full_name from company_name;" -Pfooter
full_name
"Apple inc"
"Samsun pvt, ltd"
"abc, pvt ltd"
```